# Can't write read to file even when file have full privileges

Tags: mysql, iis, centos

after publishing on IIS and executing `Mysql query select into outfile` i got the
***error code 2 : Can't write read to file ***
note that i am using centos
and the folder where i am writing have full privileges and is shared on samba

Comment: Your privileges are irrelevant, it's the account IIS is running as that needs them.

Comment: I tried the user of the pc but same error

Comment: Not user of pc, IIS service account